# Vue files not included in coverage reports

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-jest

jest: 28.1.3,
vue-jest: 3.0.7
vue: 2.7.8

my jest.config.js  is:

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,vue}', '!**/node_modules/**'],
  
  transform: {
    '^[^.]+.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      './mocks/fileMock.js',
  },
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 90,
      functions: 90,
      branches: 90,
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};
```

when I use  jest --coverage to run jest, I found some vue files not included in coverage reports,
but some vue files is ok, (Sidebar/index.vue is not in, but CommonList/Item.vue is ok):

when compare these vue compoents files, I found that when vue component file has no "import", it did not in coverage reports,
when import anything,
import something:

this vue component file can be report in coveage reports:

so what happened and what should I do ?

Comment: Hi, not sure if this will help you or anyone else.. but I found the fix for our codebase was to use `coverageProvider: 'v8'`. _The default is `'babel'`_. I'm not super certain if this is a requirement for vue and jest tests from v28 onwards.. but it fixed it for us.

One thing I should mention though.. I found that I also needed to delete the `coverage` directory once before re-generating coverage. Must be something funky going on with the cache or something. Clearing of my cache via all the different ways available did not solve this for me. It needs to be a deletion of the directory.